# ReactiveUI and CanExecute: How to validate boolean variables

Tags: c#, reactiveui, avaloniaui

Because of AvaloniaUI I am confronted with ReactiveCommands. While the excecution part is quite easy, I would like to manage the canexecute part. In particular, I need to check some boolean properties of a socket. As they change asynchronously, I would like to enable or disable a button accordingly. Lets say:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        OnButton_Clicked = ReactiveCommand.Create(OnButtonClicked, CanClickButton);
    }
    
    private Socket Socket { get; set; }
    
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OnDiscover_Clicked { get; }
    
    private void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        // Do something
    }
    
    private bool CanClickButton()
    {
        return Socket?IsAvailable;
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work like that. ReactiveCommand requieres some observeable object, which in turn seems to rely on IPropertyChanged, but that again is not provided by the Socket. How can I achieve a periodic check of a boolean variable in the canexecute function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you stated in your question the `ReactiveCommand` requires an `IObservable<bool>`

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        IObservable<bool> canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Socket.IsAvailable);
        OnDiscover_Clicked = ReactiveCommand.Create(OnButtonClicked, canExecute);
    }

    private Socket Socket { get; set;     }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OnDiscover_Clicked { get; }

    private void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Note that your socket class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order for `this.WhenAnyValue` to work, so you could create something like a `SocketViewModel` which wraps the socket.

Comment: So in the end this requires the implementation of some kind of polling, preferably by a separate task.

Comment: @Bob_Foo It’s not polling `IObservable` is a pub sub pattern, so the subscribers get notified when something changes, whereas polling requires you to periodically check whether there has been a change. You can find more info on RX.Net [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html)

Comment: @Bob_Foo is the answer I gave acceptable or were you looking for something else? :))

Comment: Sorry, had to revoke the marking. It seems, that periodically evaluating a boolean variable is the hardest thing to do in Rx.

Comment: @Bob_Foo Sorry, but I can't help you if you don't give me more information on what is going wrong. The approach I gave you works fine for me locally.

Comment: So, I have to apologize: Your suggested solution indeed works.
I experimented with the Reactive library and the program behaved unpredictable. Since I am running the app on a mobile device, Reacytive and anything regarding tasking and scheduling behaves unpredictable too, hence why asyncronous polling did was a bad idea.

Comment: @Bob_Foo No worries, good to hear that it's working for you now :))